# gatsby-remark-image-attributes not working

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

Has anyone used gatsby-remark-image-attributes? My image displays but the styling does not work.

"This plugin can handle already processed images (type: ‘html’), as long as the node object contains an attributes field and the value an  tag." This is from the docs - not sure how to add an attributes field to the node which might be where I am messing up.

Here is my image inside a md file:

```
![01](/NarrativeExport/01_3L8A0607.jpg#margin-bottom=200px;)
```

Here is my config (I am using it like in the example on it's page on the Gatsby site with gatsby-remark-images):

```
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [

          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1500,
              quality: 100,
              // wrapperStyle: 'margin-bottom:100px' **This also does not work for me
            },
          },
          `remark-image-attributes`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-image-attributes`,
            options: {
              styleAttributes: [`margin-bottom`],
            },
          }
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
```

Answer (score 0):

Width `gatsby-remark-image-attributes` you also need to use `remark-image-attributes` plugin in your gatsby config for it to work

```
`gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
        options: {
          maxWidth: 1500,
          quality: 100,
        },
      },
      `remark-image-attributes`,
      {
        resolve: "gatsby-remark-image-attributes",
        options: {
          styleAttributes: [`margin-bottom`],
        },
      }
    ],
  },
},
`gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
```

Once you do that, your image margin-bottom attribute will be used like

```
![01](/NarrativeExport/01_3L8A0607.jpg#margin-bottom=200px;)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it does not work. Updated the config code in post to reflect that.